# Setting up Ubuntu One address book

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, contacts

I deleted the Ubuntu One address book from Evolution, but now want to use it. Suddenly realized what brilliant service I lost :) How to set up Ubuntu One address book again?
Couldn't find the details that I need to enter, like the type service, or server URL. I set up everything else: Ubuntu One Account, the Ubuntu One program on my PC, so just need to make my Contact sync.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as adding the desktop couch contacts book back, like so:

[image: Add Address Book]

From the New menu under contacts you can add an Address Book, that will show a window which you can put the type as CouchDB, give it a name such as "Ubuntu One" and then select "Desktop CouchDB" as the Server.

**More detail:** This ties into this couch file in your home directory which is automatically added to your ubuntu one account:

[image: Desktop Couch files in local settings]

Assuming deleting the address book from Evolution didn't delete this file, then you should have a working and syncing address book.